# Image Border right side not showing when window is resized

Tags: html, border, window-resize

I'm kinda new to coding html so I copied a mobile-friendly template from cerberus for my job. My current problem is that I have added a border to the header image, however when the window is resized to anything less than 100%, the right border does not show. I have tried removing width:100%, that actually makes it worse. I have also tried to add padding, but that doesn't seem to work either. Below is the code please any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="email-container" role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px;" width="100%"><!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><img align="middle" alt="alt_text" aria-hidden="true" border="0" class="fluid" src="https://......" style="width: 100%; max-width: 660px; border: 10px groove goldenrod; height: auto; background: rgb(221, 221, 221) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(85, 85, 85);" width="680" /></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1: use `box-sizing: border-box;` so your width include border as a box:

> **CSS3 box-sizing Property Definition and Usage**
>
> The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.
>
> Should they include the border-box? Or just the content-box (which is the default value of the width and height properties)?
>
> **content-box:**
> Default. The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes only the content. Border, padding, or margin are not included
>
> **border-box:**
> The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin
>
> **initial:**
> Sets this property to its default value. Read about initial
>
> **inherit:**
> Inherits this property from its parent element. Read about inherit

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

```css
.fluid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 680px;
  border: 10px groove goldenrod;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(221, 221, 221) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="email-container" role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px;" width="100%">
  <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><img align="middle" alt="alt_text" aria-hidden="true" border="0" class="fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="680" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Solution 2: use the following in your `.fluid` because width does not include border width:

`width: calc(100% - 20px);`

```css
.fluid {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 10px groove goldenrod;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(221, 221, 221) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}
```

```html
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="email-container" role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px;" width="100%">
  <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><img align="middle" alt="alt_text" aria-hidden="true" border="0" class="fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="680" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i had tried number 2, big math person, but I couldn't figure out the proper format for a calculation. thx.

Comment: @MatthewG Cool, Welcome to stackOverflow, If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!